# how to use getErrorResolutionPendingIntent to check google play service

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am trying to create a common function to check whether the google play service is available or not. As i am creating a common function i am not using `getErrorDialog` as it requires a reference of `Activity`.

I have saw few more options in it like `getErrorResolutionPendingIntent`, but i dont know how to use it.

here is the code

```
    public static boolean isGooglePlayServiceAvailable(Activity activity){

        GoogleApiAvailability googleService = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();

        int result = googleService.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getContext());
        if(result != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
            if(googleService.isUserResolvableError(result)){

                PendingIntent pendingResults = googleService.getErrorResolutionPendingIntent(getContext(), new ConnectionResult(result));               


            }else{

                Log.e(TAG , "Device not supported");
            }
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[PendingIntent.send](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#send()) will perform any action related to this intent. Also from docs

> If hasResolution() is true, then getResolution() will be returned.
>   Otherwise, the returned PendingIntent will direct the user to either
>   the Play Store if Google Play services is out of date or missing, or
>   system settings if Google Play services is disabled on the device.

Comment: how to use it if i want to implement it in above code